# jQuery - SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, jquery, replace, syntax-error, contains

I try to create dynamic text replacements by combining jquery and php. But it's returning error even there is nothing wrong.

Here is the code I use:

```
    <?php
    $txt = "name, test, example";
    $texts = explode(",", $txt);
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       <?php
      foreach($texts as $key => $text){
      ?>
       $("body:contains('<?php echo $text; ?>')").html(function(_, html) {
         return html.replace(/(<?php echo $text; ?>)/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>');
       });
     <?php
     }
     ?>
     });
</script>
```

And here is the error I get:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    ..."body:contains('<span class="smallcaps">usage</span>')").html(function(_, html)
```

The arrow of the debugger is pointing to the beginning of `"smallcaps"` string on the error log above.

What could be the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: you don't have the closing ) after .html(function(_, html) . You need a second ) there.

Comment: no, it is just the debugger report. the actual code is the above one.

Comment: Woops, my bad. It might be because your `<?php echo $text;?>` needs to be sanitized. It looks to be inserting a double quote there?